# Intellij is stealing focus from editor after compile

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 9.0.2
After each make, if i have errors, window "messages Make" is stealing focus from the main editor. Do you know how to correct this?

Comment: which look and feel are you using? does this problem persist with the default?

Comment: I changed look and feel to "IDEA (4.5 default)" but that didn't help. You don't this problem with your Intellij IDEA?

Steps to reproduce:

1) Make an error (e.g. don't close the curly bracket)
2) Click Ctrl+F9
3) Continue typing in editor. When compiler finds the error, you can't type anymore, because focus is in the "messages" window now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change this behavior in the configuration. There is a keyboard shortcut which allows you to change focus to specific 'windows' within IDEA.

CTRL+SHIFT+TAB

CTRL is probably replaced with CMD on Mac and Super (windows key) on Unix. This will allow you to manually switch back to the editor tab of your choice, or any other window for that matter.

Comment: on Mac it is CTRL too :)

Answer (score 1):

ESC does the trick for me in intelli 12.